# Getting value of objects from results of symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try get from database id value from User Entity.

```
            $id = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyappUserBundle:User')->findByUsername($username);
```

and i get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\User Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 1
            [age:protected] => 22
            [city:protected] => 
            [state:protected] => 
            [sex:protected] => 
            [avatar:protected] => 99small-man-dancing-with-cat.jpg
            [username:protected] => yeps
etc...
```

I have question:

How can I get id value from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findByX` returns an array where as `findOneByX` will return a single object.

As you are searching for a specific username it would make more send to use `findOneByX` and then you can get the `id` from the return `User` like..

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MyappUserBundle:User')
    ->findOneByUsername($username)
;

$id = $user->getId();
```

It would also make sense to add a null check incase no user was found like..

```
if (null === $user) {
    throw new \Exception(sprintf('User with username "%s" not found', $username));
}

$id = $user->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

The "findByUsername" method returns a User object, so in order to get the user id (assuming you already have a "getId" public function in your User entity) you would have to do something like this:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyappUserBundle:User')->findByUsername($username);
$userId = $user->getId();
```